# Remote login (ssh differences)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, grep

I would like to know what is the difference  between the below commands:

```
ssh vagrant@someipaddress
cd /home/vagrant/
grep -i "something" data.txt
```

and

```
ssh vagrant@someipaddress 'cd /home/vagrant; cat data.txt' | grep -i "something"
```

From this [website](https://thornelabs.net/2013/08/21/simple-ways-to-send-multiple-line-commands-over-ssh.html) it mentions, that you can send multiple commands to the remote server. Is the second option actually logging into the server? What is the benefit in this second approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strictly Speaking** from the example provided:

The **first** command:

- Logs onto the remote server
- Executes a couple commands, and
- Stays logged on to the server

The **second** command runs half on the remote machine, logs out of the remote machine, and then pipes the output to `grep` on your local machine, all in one command line.

### Breaking down what's happening:

```
ssh vagrant@someipaddress 'cd /home/vagrant; cat data.txt' | grep -i "something"
```

- The section in bold is running on your local PC, based on the output from the `ssh` session
- The `'`quotes "contain" the entire command block
- the `"` quotes "contain" the individual *arguments* within the command block.

**You may have meant to do this:**

```
ssh vagrant@someipaddress 'cd /home/vagrant; cat data.txt' | grep -i "something"
```

- Where the bold section runs locally

**Or you may have intentionally done this:**

```
 ssh vagrant@someipaddress 'cd /home/vagrant/ | grep -i "something" data.txt'
```

- Where the entire command runs on the server.

#### Either way, the end result:

- Is that you automatically log out of the remote machine, and the whole command sequence was executed in one hit.